# React Server side render error RendetoString token error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs

can anybody tell what's wrong in this code?

In server.js file, I am tried to import @babel/register also still it's giving me error. I tried all possible answer which available on the internet

serverRenderer

```
import React from 'react';
import config from '../config';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import axios from 'axios';
import App from '../Components/App';
import DataApi from '../state-api'

const serverRender = async () => {
    const resp = await axios.get(`http://${config.host}: ${config.port}/data`);
    const api = new DataApi(resp.data);
    const initialData = { articles: api.getArticles(), authors: api.getAuthors() };
    const content = renderToString(<App initialData={initialData} />);
    return content;
}

export default serverRender;
```

npm run command

```
 nodemon lib/server.js --exec babel-node --presets @babel/preset-env, @babel/preset-react
```

hers is the error I am getting

```
/home/rackham/dev/advanceReact/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/parser/index.js:95
    throw err;
    ^

SyntaxError: /home/rackham/dev/advanceReact/lib/renderers/serverRender.js: Unexpected token (12:32)

  10 |  const api = new DataApi(resp.data);
  11 |  const initialData = { articles: api.getArticles(), authors: api.getAuthors() };
> 12 |  const content = renderToString(<App initialData={initialData} />);
     |                                 ^
  13 |  return content;
  14 | }
  15 | 
    at Parser._raise (/home/rackham/dev/advanceReact/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/location.js:241:45)
    at Parser.raiseWithData (/home/rackham/dev/advanceReact/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/location.js:236:17)
    at Parser.raise (/home/rackham/dev/advanceReact/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/location.js:220:17)
    at Parser.unexpected (/home/rackham/dev/advanceReact/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/util.js:149:16)
    at Parser.parseExprAtom (/home/rackham/dev/advanceReact/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:1144:20)
    at Parser.parseExprSubscripts (/home/rackham/dev/advanceReact/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:539:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (/home/rackham/dev/advanceReact/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:519:21)
    at Parser.parseExprOps (/home/rackham/dev/advanceReact/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:311:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeConditional (/home/rackham/dev/advanceReact/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:263:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeAssign (/home/rackham/dev/advanceReact/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:211:21) {
  loc: Position { line: 12, column: 32 },
  pos: 488,
  code: 'BABEL_PARSE_ERROR'
}
```

Comment: Did you create .babelrc file with presets ?

Comment: No here I am not using webpack